# Using razorpages with entity framework and full calendar doesn't show events

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, razor-pages

I have a problem with full calendar work with Entity Framework in the front end. The data is current but isn't visible on web page.
The web page just show the canladar.
I have refer to another topic and that didn't solved my problem .

([Using razorpages entity framework to work with full calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646864/using-razorpages-entity-framework-to-work-with-full-calendar))

**Backend Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RotaryDeuxPlateaux.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MyApp.Pages
{
    public class calendrierModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly db_Context _db;


        public IList<TblEvenement> Events { get; set; }
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;


        [BindProperty]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Doc { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string Pat { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string dec { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        //private Schedule schedule;
       [BindProperty]
        public JsonResult result { get; set; }


        public string today = DateTime.Today.ToString();

        public void OnGet()
        {

            result = (JsonResult)OnGetEvents();
            
            ViewData["CalendarEents"] = result;
        }

        public calendrierModel(db_Context context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // _logger = logger;
            _db = context;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }



        public class eventShow
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string start { get; set; }
            public string end { get; set; }


        }





        public IActionResult OnGetEvents()
        {
            List<eventShow> events = new List<eventShow>();
            eventShow show = new eventShow();
            try
            {
                //string x = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");

                using (var context = new db_rotaryContext())
                {

                    var query = from st in _db.TblEvenement
                              //  where st.Id == 1 //|| st.DoctorEmail == x.Trim()
                                select st;



                    foreach (var item in query.ToList())
                    {

                        show.id = item.IdEvenement;
                        show.title = item.TitreEvenement;
                        show.description = item.Description;
                        show.start = item.DateDebutEvenement.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        show.end = item.DateFinEvenement.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");


                        events.Add(show);
                    }


                    return new JsonResult(events);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


        //public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string searchString, int? searchDay, int? searchMonth, int? searchYear, int? pageIndex)
        //{
        //    // using System;

        //    IQueryable<TblEvenement> MembresIQ = from s in _db.TblEvenement


        //                                         select s;


        //    Events = await MembresIQ.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

        //}

    }
}
```

** HEAD OF THE PAGE LAYOUT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @*<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />*@
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

    <title>@ViewData["Title"] </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    @*<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">*@


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">


    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.0/main.min.css" integrity="sha256-lQnxfLYgySmY6nHM7LkVqcS2RdJvFUV2p6FHg04SZN4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.0/main.min.js" integrity="sha256-RYuehXpnr248jInax6L9UXEegv6DvIRoN+lyxayiIFg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },

             schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
                initialDate: '2022-06-06',
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                selectable: true,
                selectMirror: true,
        eventColor: '#378000',

                select: function (arg) {
                    var title = prompt('Evènements:');

                    if (title) {
                        var tie = prompt('Time');
                    }

                    if (title) {
                        calendar.addEvent({
                            title: title,
                            start: arg.start,
                            Starttime: tie,
                            end: arg.end,
                            EndTime: arg.EndTime
                        })
                    }
                    calendar.unselect()
                },
                eventClick: function (arg) {
                    if (confirm('Voulez-vous supprimer ?')) {


                        arg.event.remove()
                    }
                },
                editable: true,
                dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
               // events: $.getJSON('~/Calendrier/OnGetEvents')
               // events: @ViewData["CalendarEents"];
                events:"/calender?handler=events"
                //"/calender?handler=events"

            });

            calendar.render();
        });



        //$(document).ready(function ()
        //{
        //    var events = [];
        //    $.ajax({
        //        type: 'GET',
        //        url: '/Calendrier',
        //        success: function (data) {

        //            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        //                events.push({
        //                    title: v.TitreEvenement,
        //                    description: v.Description,
        //                    debut: moment(v.DateDebutEvenement),
        //                    fin: v.DateFinEvenement != null ? moment(v.DateFinEvenement) : null,
        //                    color: ThemeColor,
        //                    allDay: v.isFullDay
        //                });
        //            })

        //            GenerateCalendar(events);
        //        },
        //        error: function (error) {
        //            alert('failed');
        //        }
        //    })
        //})


        //function GenerateCalendar(events) {
        //    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        //    calendarEl.FullCalendar('destroy');
        //    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        //        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        //        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        //        defaultDate: new Date,
        //        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
        //        Headers: {
        //            left: 'prev,next toady',
        //            center: 'title',
        //            rigth: 'month,basicweek,basicDay,agenda'
        //        },
        //        eventLimit: true,
        //        eventColor: '#378000',
        //        events: events
        //    });
        //    calendar.render();
        //}


        //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        //    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        //    calendarEl.FullCalendar('destroy');
        //    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        //        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        //        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        //        defaultDate: new Date,
        //        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
        //        Headers:{
        //            left: 'prev,next toady',
        //            center: 'title',
        //            rigth: 'month,basicweek,basicDay,agenda'
        //        },
        //        eventLimit: true,
        //        eventColor: '#378000',
        //        events: events
        //    });
        //    calendar.render();
        //});

    </script>
    <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/RotaryStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body id="page-top">
```

**THE PAGE**

```
@{

 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Calendrier";

    ViewData["CalendarEents"] = Model.result;
}

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="page-section">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div id='calendar'>

                </div>
    
            </div>

        </div>

       

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the events to the viewdata? According to how you've defined the fullcalendar code, the JSON should be returned directly as the result of calling the URL in the `events:` property. The link you provided as an example doesn't do that

Comment: @ADyson Thank.                                                                            
 But i try diffrente approch without result :                                                              
1- events: "/Calendrier/events"    
2- events: "/Calendrier/result"   events: "/Calendrier?handler=events"                        
3- events: "/Calendrier?handler=OnGetEvents"                                                           
4- events: "[{ title: 'The AI Summit 2016',  start: '12/06/2022', end: '12/06/2022', backgroundColor: '#BCE4FD', borderColor: '#26A8FB'}]"

Comment: How do i know the good link to bind JSon data ?

Comment: `start: '12/06/2022', end: '12/06/2022',`...are not valid - dates must be in a parseable format such as `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Anyway I didn't tell you to change your URL, I asked you why you're returning the events to the ViewData

Comment: Because the events were not displayed. I wanted to put them in the ViewData and retrieve it in the view.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense compared with calling them from a URL in fullcalendar. You just need the endpoint to return a JSON array as per the fullcalendar documentation. Test that independently and get it working, and then hook it up to the calendar.